# record video through mediacapture plugin but issue while uploading through file plugin - ionic capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I’m using Capacitor 3 and Ionic 6 angular on Android 11.

I’ve used the **media capture plugin for recording a video** and i get a result like this:

```
[MediaFile]
0: MediaFile
end: 0
fullPath: "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20210522_185343.mp4"
lastModified: null
lastModifiedDate: 1621702425000
localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20210522_185343.mp4"
name: "20210522_185343.mp4"
size: 13596835
start: 0
type: "video/mp4"
__proto__: File
length: 1
```

Am using the **file plugin to upload it to the s3 server** but when i use the file plugin as below it neither throws any error nor gets into the response.

```
this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(fullPath, name).then(realFile => {
    console.log('realFile: ', realFile);
    console.log('readAsArrayBuffer: ', realFile.byteLength);
}, (err) => {
    this.loading.dismiss();
    console.log('readAsArrayBuffer Error: ',  JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

I need to use the **arraybuffer output to create a blob** in order to upload it.
**But it doesn't return any response or an error.**

If there is any other way to do so then please do let me know.

**Earlier in ionic 5 cordova the file plugin was working.**

Moreover, suggest me if i can explain it in more detail.

Thanks.

Below mentioned is my **ionic info:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.11
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.2.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.2.6
   @angular/cli                  : 13.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.4.3
   @capacitor/android : 3.4.3
   @capacitor/core    : 3.4.3
   @capacitor/ios     : 3.4.3

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.14.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.5.0
   OS     : macOS Monterey
```

Answer (score 0):

file plugin does not work with angular/ionic because of zone.js
[Git Hub Issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1564)

To work with file it is recommended to use capacitors own FileSystemAPI it works like a charm.
[FileSystem API](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem)